# Preferred approach for marking up a blog with Schema.org

Tags: blogs, semantic-markup, microdata, schema.org

### Background/context

As schema.org is relatively new, perhaps this question will promote more discussion than a definitive answer. Either way, hopefully some learning from others' application/experience can be gained.

Having studied the http://schema.org documentation pages – and whilst there seems to be an extensive array of properties (read: `itemprop` attributes) available to enrich a blog post, there seems to be some inconsistencies and 'grey areas' with regard to the best approach to mark up blog comments. Let me provide an example:

The schema.org documentation for blogs can be found on within [Thing > CreativeWork > Blog](http://schema.org/Blog) and for reference, a blog post lives within [Thing > CreativeWork > Article > BlogPosting](http://schema.org/BlogPosting)

So far, the documentation and markup examples on the aforementioned pages provide enough reference to format a blog index page, and the bulk of content within an individual post  (`author`, `pubDate`, `articleBody`, `interactionCount`, etc.)

### The problem: applying the UserInteraction schema to individual blog comments

It is when we start to look at individual UserInteraction elements (blog comments) within the `interactionCount` that things get a little vague. The documentation leads us through to [Thing > Event > UserInteraction > UserComments](http://schema.org/UserComments), and is described as *'User interaction: A comment about an item.'* However all of the suggested properties of `UserInteraction` are geared towards a physical event.

The only property that appears to be relevant to a blog comment in this schema's documentation is `description`; which *could* be used for the comment body. What feels lacking is some specific context for user comments about a blog post. There's also no evidence of example markup for said comments, even a [search for 'comments' on the site](http://schema.org/docs/search_results.html#q=comment) doesn't seem to yield any clarity.

Has anyone marked up their blog using schema.org – and how did you approach/solve this?

I'll also raise this matter via the schema.org feedback form and update this post if anything comes to light.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the examples here http://schema.org/WebPage and notice how the reviews are used for the Books.

You can do the same for Comments in Article, here's an example:

```
 <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"> 

     <-- Article content -->

     <div itemprop="comment" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments">     
       <meta itemprop="discusses" content="A masterpiece of literature" />             
       <span itemprop="creator">John Doe</span>   
       <time itemprop="commentTime" datetime="2011-05-08T19:30">May 8, 7:30pm</time>    

       <span itemprop="commentText">I really enjoyed this book. It captures the essential  
       challenge people face as they try make sense of their lives.</span>    
     </div>

     <div itemprop="comment" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments">     
       <meta itemprop="discusses" content="A masterpiece of literature" />             
       <span itemprop="creator">John Doe</span>   
       <time itemprop="commentTime" datetime="2011-05-08T19:30">May 8, 7:30pm</time>    

       <span itemprop="commentText">I really enjoyed this book. It captures the essential  
       challenge people face as they try make sense of their lives.</span>    
     </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Excellent fleshed-out example of UserComments -- thanks for posting this. Been digging around all over and couldn't find anything explicitly showing this implementation (particularly on schema.org). +1

Comment: Excellent – just what I needed too!

Comment: Great example, just what I was looking for (but somehow must have missed!). Thank you @Ervald

Comment: I have few doubts about the example you suggested. In the example there a list of `Review` (singular form). But since `UserComments` is a plural form, it should contain a list of comments and not be part of a list.

Answer (score 5):

Some years later, http://schema.org/Comment has been introduced.

> A comment on an item - for example, a comment on a blog post. The comment's content is expressed via the "text" property, and its topic via "about", properties shared with all CreativeWorks.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that `UserComments` is *not* for marking up blog comments. It exists only as one of the possible interaction types to be used with the `interactionCount` property on [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork), such as:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <span itemprop="http://schema.org/interactionCount">UserComments:7</span>
</div>
```

I would mark up each of the comments as a `CreativeWork` or `Article`, and make sure that their `about` property points to the blog post that they are commenting to.

Comment: Your suggestion certainly seems to provide a logical application – and I can see the how valuable the `about` property is for us to associate comments to an article when they appear out of the document flow (i.e. somewhere else on the page/on a separate page altogether). Cheers for that alone!

However it still seems an oddity that there is a dedicated page in the schema.org documentation made for `Usercomments` http://schema.org/UserComments

I've implemented the `interactionCount` as above, and for now think I'll follow your suggestion above unless anything else comes to light. Thanks

Comment: p.s. I'd up-vote your answer if I had more reputation - I'd also like to implement your response before marking it as answered if that's ok!

Comment: I think you are mistaken: `Blog` (which is a more specific `CreativeWork`) lists the prop `comment`, which is a `UserComments` schema. And `UserComments` has props like `commentText` and `commentTime`. That seems a lot more specific and appropriate than marking up comments as a `CreativeWork` or `Articles`.

Answer (score 1):

Blaise appears to be correct as of now. The example used on schema.org/Comment is:

> A comment on an item - for example, a comment on a blog post. The comment's content is expressed via the "text" property, and its topic via "about", properties shared with all CreativeWorks.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like the `<meta>` approach when I have the content matching the data. Since schema.org is not yet fully documented, I went ahead with this:

```
<span itemprop="interactionCount">100</span>
```

and/or this:

```
<span itemprop="interactionCount">100 comments</span>
```

I know that it doesn't specify "UserComments" anywhere. Thoughts?